# Hosting DNS to allow reverse lookup

Tags: dns, self-hosting, reverse-dns

I've only recently begun scratching the surface of hosting my own DNS, but I'm looking to do so in the hopes that I can facilitate my own reverse lookups.

My idea being that if I can manage my own DNS, I can give it tables I've complied about IP / FQDN relations so I can do a reverse lookups on dynamic ips (of which I know the FQDN of) without my ISP's support; I'd pair the return of something like an nslookup somewhere within my own hosted DNS then have that DNS server facilitate reverse DNS lookups for some programs that require the function (like for a CFEngine Hub)
Near as I can tell, the 'PRT' record is what I want to spoof; [Right?](https://www.siteground.com/kb/what_is_a_ptr_record_and_how_to_add_one/)

I'm wondering if there are better resources out in the wild to use. [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/245707/not-able-to-get-the-reverse-dns-working) and [this](http://www.itworld.com/article/2833006/networking/how-to-setup-reverse-dns-and-ptr-records.html) are the best I've found about hosting DNS in this manner.

Any pitfalls I'm not seeing about trying to pursue this convoluted solution?

Answer (score 0):

Reverse lookup requires the IP address owner to delegate reverse lookup DNS to you. Note that the owner here is not the DHCP recipient, but whoever assigns the IP address.

For a completely internal network, it would be possible to configure your own PTR records since you control the IP addresses being assigned.

On third party networks, the third party (who assigns IP addresses to you) would need to delegate reverse lookup for those IPs to you. In a dynamic IP situation, this delegation is unlikely because your IP comes out of a pool that is used for assigning IP addresses to many customers, not just you. Some ISPs allow allow programmatic access to configure reverse lookups, but this again seems unlikely for dynamic DNS for the same reason as delegation -- the addresses are part of pool assigned to any customer using it, not just you.

It might be possible to hack ("shadow"?) it by requiring your users / clients to use your DNS server and populating "fake" (since you don't actually have ownership of the IPs) PTR records.

Article on reverse lookup sequence and info.
http://www.dnsstuff.com/reverse-dns-faq

A way around this might be to create your own tool for looking through your forward lookup table for a specific IP address.  However, this would be a custom tool separate from the usual DNS lookup tools like nslookup and dig.